# FadeOut iff rails instance variable is equal one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

At my view there is a table with some entries, these can be deleted by use of remote and javascript:

```
$("#entry_<%=@id%>").fadeOut(150, function(){
 $(this).remove();
});
```

There is also a button at this view, which should fadeOut iff the rails variable **@size** in my controller is equal to 1.

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the button rendered and then fadeOut as soon as the page is loaded?  Or you could just not render the button at all if @size == 1.

Comment: @size holds the count how many entries at the tabel are left, if there only one entry left i want fadeOut the button as soon as the page is loaded.

Comment: @dot it's js.erb file or js file? if it's a js.erb file then you can't have a page load and if it's a js file then you can't use variables inside it.

Comment: Oh k so I understand it a little bit wrong sry, it is a **js.erb** file, which is called every time when I delete an entry at the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said it's a **js.erb** file so *you can use ruby statements inside it so simply check for your variable and use js inside its block something like:*

```
<% if @size == 1 %>
  $("#some_id_of_button").fadeout();
<% end %>
```